# Calculating Loss function for kmeans in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataframe containing 5 columns. I am trying to cluster the points for three variables `X`, `Y` and `Z` and find the loss function for kmeans clustering. The following code takes care of that, but if I run this for my real dataframe with `160,000` row, it takes for ever! I assume it can be done a lot faster.

PS: It seems that `KMeans` module in `sklearn` does not provide the loss function that's why I am writing my own code.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 5), columns=list('XYZVW'))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 6, random_state = 0).fit(df[['X','Y', 'Z']].values)
df['Cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
loss = 0.0
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    cluster = int(df.loc[i, "Cluster"])
    a = np.array(df.loc[i,['X','Y', 'Z']])
    b = kmeans.cluster_centers_[cluster]
    loss += np.linalg.norm(a-b)
print(loss)
```

Comment: Avoid Python code such as your for loop. The interpreter is slow. Vectorize your operations!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `scipy` package takes care of the loss function and it is pretty fast. Here's the code:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq, kmeans, whiten
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 5), columns=list('XYZVW'))
centers, loss = kmeans(df[['X','Y', 'Z']].values, 6)
df['Cluster'] = vq(features, centers)[0]
```

That being said, I am still interested to know the fastest way of calculating loss function using `sklearn` `kmeans` module.

Comment: Why scipy loss and ahoosh's method are different?

Answer (score 2):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

> inertia_ : float
>
> > Sum of distances of samples to their closest cluster center.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed use of the euclidean norm is not correct.

As @Has QUIT--Anony-Mousse mentioned, what we want is the sum of squared distances to the nearest centroid, also known as intertia.

This is how **intertia is computed with custom vectorized code**, matching sklearn:

```
loss = (np.expand_dims(X,1)-kmeans.cluster_centers_)**2 # (N_BATCH,N_CLUSTERS,N_FEATURES)
loss = loss.sum(-1).min(-1) # minimize sum of squares 
loss = loss.sum() # aggregate over a data batch or dataset
loss
```